# how can i make natural key values unqiue with a function

Tags: python

is there a way I can create a function to prevent my unique key values from changing, or raise an error if there is an attempt to change unique keys values? i am writing an update function for a database to update entries, but i want to make it so if the "unique key values " are in the payload to be updated it will raise an error

```
mydict = {
'name': 'cameron', # natural keys
'age': '29',       #also natural key
'city': 'boston',
}
```

Comment: In what context? What have you tried?

Comment: What is your definition of natural key?

Comment: Instead of using a `dict` (which is generally intended to be mutable), consider a different data structure that better fits your problem statement.  Maybe a `class` where `name` and `age` are `property`s whose `setter` function raises an exception?

Comment: sorry for the poor explanation, a natural keys as i understand would be the values are unique. the dictionary is an entry for a database and i need the values on the first two keys to be unique per entry.

Comment: for better explanation i am writing an update function for a database to update entries, but i want to make it so if the "natural keys" are in the payload to be updated it will raise an error

Comment: @CameronBogucki: The preferred method is, to put additional information into the question via, since comments are more volatile.

Comment: if "natural keys" aren't included in the payload, how do you know which database entry to update?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at existing database designs, they typically only allow updating entire database entries, the dict in your case, rather than only a part of the entry.

An update function would typically look like:

```
natural_keys = ['name', 'age']
database: Dict[tuple, dict]: ...

def update(new_entry: dict):
    keys = tuple(new_entry[k] for k in natural_keys)
    if keys in database:  # update existing entries
       database[keys] = new_entry
    else:  # raise error if there are no entries with these natural keys
       raise ValueError(f"there are no entries with natural keys {keys}")
```

This way you will never really change the natural keys, only updating existing entries with the same natural keys.

Of course, you will need an `insert` function to insert new entries with new natural keys.

So there is never really the problem of preventing user from changing natural keys.

### Alternatively

For detailed controls, you can create a class and control property setting via property setter

For example,

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self, name, age, city):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self.city = city

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        raise ValueError("can't set name")

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        raise ValueError("can't set age")
```

So you can define

```
my_dict = MyDict(name='cameron', age=29, city='boston')
```

You can set `city`

```
my_dict.city = 'new york'
```

But you will get `ValueError` when you try to set `name` and `age`.

In more advanced usage, you can use descriptors to handle general attribute setting

```
import logging


class PreventSetting:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        logging.info('Accessing %r giving %r', self.public_name, value)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        # if defining for 1st time
        if not hasattr(obj, self.private_name):
            logging.info('Updating %r to %r', self.public_name, value)
            setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)
        else:
            # raise error for setting value after 1st time
            raise ValueError(f"can't set {self.public_name}")


class MyDict:
    name = PreventSetting()  # First descriptor instance
    age = PreventSetting()  # Second descriptor instance

    def __init__(self, name, age, city):
        self.name = name  # Calls the first descriptor __set__
        self.age = age  # Calls the second descriptor __set__
        self.city = city
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple example will be as follows:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    NATURAL_KEYS = ["name", "age"]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.NATURAL_KEYS:
            raise KeyError(f"My natural key `{key}`'s value is prevented from changing.")

        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

[image]

You can read more info here: https://realpython.com/inherit-python-dict/#creating-dictionary-like-classes-in-python.